# Сложный SQL запрос, логикой похожий на DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть три таблицы

```
release
------------
id |  title 
1     Some
2     Some
3     Some

artist
------------
id | title
1     Artist1
2     Artist2 

release_2_artist
------------
id | release_id | artist_id 
1       1           1
2       2           1
3       3           2
```

Нужен запрос результатом которого станет:

```
  release.id  | release.title
        1           Some       
        3           Some
```

Запрос вида `SELECT DISTINCT('title'), id FROM release WHERE 1`, возвращает только одну запись. В базе на 70к записей потеря контента составляет около 7к.

суть вопроса: Для каждого исполнителя, выбрать альбомы с уникальным title. 
Реально ли это сделать одним запросом SQL, без костылей на PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT release.id as release_id, release.title
FROM `release_2_artist`
JOIN `release` ON release.id = release_2_artist.release_id
GROUP BY release_2_artist.artist_id, release.title
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что такой запрос подойдёт:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  r2a.release_id AS release_id,
  r.title AS title
FROM
  release_2_artist r2a
  JOIN release r ON r2a.release_id = r.id;
```

Столбцы в ответе у меня называются чуть по-другому, чем у Вас в вопросе, но псевдонимы-то Вы любые сочинить можете)